# Render view when login via facebook

Tags: php, facebook, yii2

I want to show user `first_name` and `last_name` when he logged in my site via `Facebook` widget. But when I'm logging nothing happened, I see just my index page.

**My controller:**

```
public function actions() {
    return [
        'auth' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
            'successCallback' => [$this, 'oAuthSuccess'],
        ],
    ];
}

public function oAuthSuccess($client) {
    // get user data from client
    $userAttributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
    return $this->render('say', [
        'first_name' => $userAttributes['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $userAttributes['last_name'],
    ]);
    // do some thing with user data. for example with $userAttributes['email']
}
```

**My view say.php:**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<?= Html::encode($first_name) ?>
<?= Html::encode($last_name) ?>
```

Comment: Are you actually getting back a first name and last name? You can run `var_dump($userAttributes);` before the return to confirm.

Comment: I used var_dump and I have array with data in pop-up window, but in main window nothing happening.

Comment: Can you post the `authClientCollection` config? (without your clientId and clientSecret ofcourse)